# why does the encrypt function don't show any error but doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an academy project for encrypting all from some path and I have some problems like this [for list recursive directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937915/how-to-list-directory-and-its-subdirectories-and-its-files-in-python/71938031#71938031), I finally solved and now the code run without problems but doesn't execute anything. Does someone have an idea what may be going on?

The code is this:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
from pathlib import PurePath


def generar_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open('key.key', 'wb') as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)


def cargar_key():
    return open('key.key', 'rb').read()


def encrypt(items, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    for item in items:
        with open(item, 'rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
        encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
        with open(item, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encrypted_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ROOT = r"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\archivos" #path to encrypt

    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(ROOT): #for list the sub-directories of the path
        for name in files:
            pure_path = PurePath(path, name)

    items = os.listdir(path)
    full_path = [path + '\\' + item for item in items] #for list the files of the path

    generar_key()
    key = cargar_key()

    encrypt(full_path, key)

    with open(ROOT + '\\' + 'llegeix.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('Text\n')
        file.write('+ text')
```

Comment: What do you find if you strategically add some print statements to see which parts of the code are executed in which order? At what point is something not executed that you expected to be executed, or in a different order than you expected?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the thing is that the code execute but doesn't do anything, i put some print statements and i confirmed that the process enter in the encrypt function and do the two steps of the function but doesn't encrypt nothing.

Comment: How do you know that it encrypts nothing?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for you to use a debugger where you can set breakpoints and check for variable values while the script runs. Most IDEs offer a debugger and from my own experience I can suggest PyCharm (which you can get as a student for free), as it offers pretty thorough debugging and interactive code execution.
For example, you could check that in the function

```py
def encrypt(items, key):
    f = Fernet(key)
    for item in items:
        with open(item, 'rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
        encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)
        with open(item, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encrypted_data)
```

the `items` list is not empty. This would be an error that happens to me a lot -- if the list is empty for some reason, nothing will happen of course.

Other than that, mkrieger1 already suggested to use print statements, which of course could also help if you don't have a debugger handy.

Comment: thx @Stimmot for the suggest, i work with pycharm, and the debugger doesn't show me any error, but i check what items i'm sending to the function encrypt and i think i found the problem, the function only recive the files of one sub-directorie and only encrypt that.